# How to get a value from Html table inside a row which has a multiple values

Tags: javascript, html

Actually i am receiving a response from server which i am displaying it front view using javascript and if i want to click on each row i need to capture the value so how can i do it.There will not be a two elements it must contain a 100 rows also it is a dynamic data row added i am showing currently with two columns.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function getVal(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;

    alert(targ.innerHTML);
}

onload = function() {
    var t = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("td");
    for ( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
        t[i].onclick = getVal;
}

</script>
<body>
<table id="main"  style="width:29%">

   <tr  style="cursor: pointer;">
    <td>
    <br>
      HJCU4982531&nbsp;
      RD<br>
      L702B2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong style="color:#FF0000">  &gt;&gt; </strong>
      260307<hr>
    </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr  style="cursor: pointer;">
    <td>
    <br>
      MSKU4614240&nbsp;
      LL<br>
      L702E1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong style="color:#FF0000">  &gt;&gt; </strong>
      PM<hr>
    </td>
    </tr>  

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to capture the MSKU4614240 when i click on the table row

Comment: I think it's simpler to also put that value in a table cell tag data attribute, or wrap it in a span tag, when you write out that table. Easier to grab then.

Answer (score 0):

You speak about table rows but actually your table is one column only so you can work on the single td. Wrap the content of each td in a a tag with id="MSKU4614240" and on click you can retrieve the value. Please note that this works only if the value you use as identifier is unique and is not repeated in more than one cell each time the table is displayed.
Note, this way you can click only on the content. If you want to click on the whole table cell you can style the  link as

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

so it will fit the whole cell.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you want to retrieve that ID from the innerHTML

you can do this with the following code (replace your alert with the following)

```
var start = targ.innerHTML.indexOf('<br>') + 4; // +4 so we start from end of <br>
var end = targ.innerHTML.indexOf('&nbsp;');

alert(targ.innerHTML.substring(start, end));
```

1. search for the `<br>` before the ID
2. search for the `&nbsp;` after the ID
3. take string between the 2 elements (the ID)

but the fix is not very nice

if you wrap that id inside his own HTML element then the code would look a lot nicer